# Why is the body of my ajax multipart/form-data POST request empty?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have the following form in my html:

```
<form id="formid" action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

I submit a POST request via ajax as follows:

```
function upload_ajax(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var form = $("#formid");
  var formData = new FormData(form);

  xhr.open("post", form.attr('action') , true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

But when I select a file and run upload_ajax(), the file is not sent to the server. On examining the POST request I can see that the body is empty (except for a boundary:------WebKitFormBoundaryzRrtLc7ACnj5mKtE--).

Everything works fine if I replace upload_ajax() with upload_normal() below:

```
function upload_normal(){
   $('#formid').submit();
}
```

Can anyone help my understand what I am doing wrong in my ajax call?

Comment: are you accessing `$_POST` or `$_FILES` ?

Comment: The server side is not written by me. This is a google app engine application and this upload is going to Google blobstore for which we are only allowed to use Google's own server. (I am accessing the POST data using chrome developer tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is that `$("#formid")` is jquery Object and not the form.

to access the form write:

`var form = $("#formid")[0];`